# Why does "hot chocolate powder" lose taste?

Tags: flavor, chocolate

Yesterday, I made hot chocolate with ["Schokotraum Typ Trinkschokolade" from Krüger](https://krueger.de/gesamtsortiment/produkt/family/schoko-traum-typ-trinkschokolade/). I was very surprised, that it didn't taste sweet at all (which is bad; it didn't have a lot of taste overall).

The ingredients are:

> DE: Zucker, Süßmolkenpulver (32,3%), Kakaopulver (25,5%), Magermilchpulver (6%), Speisesalz.
>
> EN: Sugar, sweet whey powder (32.3%), cocoa powder (25.5%), skimmed milk powder (6%), salt

I opened it last year and it should be good until November 2020. I don't quite remember, but I think it was sweet last year

Why didn't it taste sweet?

Comment: Welcome! Just double-checking: did you eat anything before or together with the drink? Brushed your teeth or suffer from a cold or congested nose? In other words, can we exclude a perception issue?

Answer (score 2):

The best before date is often only valid until the pack is opened.
I'd check the pack itself for confirmation, but many goods will say "Best before *[2 years]*" but then underneath something along the lines of "Once opened keep in *[circumstances]* & consume within *[much shorter time]*"

I first looked up shelf life of cocoa powder - essentially it will last several years if kept cool & dry, but will lose flavour long before eventually going off. Long-term it can go rancid & become unsafe, but long before that it will simply lose all its chocolate flavour.
I couldn't find any absolute authoritative citation for this; it was an opinion formed from many sources, quoting similar but not identical information.

Sweet whey powder, on the other hand, has a shelf life of only 6 - 12 months, according to [Dairy for Global Nutrition](https://www.dairyglobalnutrition.org/safety-and-quality/shelf-life-and-packaging)*. Similar anecdotal sources to those for cocoa powder above say this will also lose flavour & eventually smell & taste like milk gone off. [This search is hindered by the number of results for protein whey powder, which rather bury those for sweet whey.]

> *Dry dairy products are known for having a neutral, mild dairy flavor.
>   Storage at high temperatures and high relative humidity may increase
>   the potential development of off-flavors. In many cases, significant
>   changes in product flow and solubility will occur before any changes
>   in flavor and aroma become evident. **Flavor changes develop more
>   quickly in agglomerated or "instant" ingredients.**

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

In conclusion, I imagine that what you tasted was not so much 'less sugar' as less 'chocolate' & potentially slightly past its best sweet whey.